Can not compile VIM with python support for non-system python
I try to compile VIM with python interpreter enabled.
Yet, I've got Ubuntu 20.04 (can not update easily) with Python 3.8 as system version. I need VIM with Python >3.9.
I installed python3.10 and libpython3.10 to compile.
I run this command to configure it:
./configure \
  --prefix=/usr/local \
  --with-features=huge \ 
  --with-x \
  --enable-python3interp=yes \
  --with-python3-config-dir=$(python3.10-config --configdir) \
  --with-python3-command=python3.10

and I still get
checking --enable-pythoninterp argument... no
checking --enable-python3interp argument... no

No need to tell you vim --version still tell me -python3. This is not enabled.
It seems VIM configure can not take this option into account. It does not find the python dependencies.
What's wrong here?
I saw this solution which tell not to use the deprecated option --with-python3-config-dir but it does not work either...
Merry christmas to everyone :)

What exact packages did you install?

I made sudo apt-get install python3.10 libpython3.10-dev python3.10-dev

You should add that info to the question.

Try with the --verbose option?

IIRC the homebrew recipe also sets PYTHONPATH or similar in the environment when compiling. I generally use it as inspiration

verbose option does not exist :(
